# transfer images path from excel spread sheet to html file

Tags: html, excel, csv

I am trying to covert spread sheet with hundreds of image path to html pages. For example:

```
excel sheet
imageId    imagePath   

1           images/ima1
2           images/ima2
3           images/ima3
...         .........
...          ........
```

Are there faster ways to covert these images to html files instead of typing them 1 by 1?

The html files I need is like the following:

```
<img src=images/ima1 title='ima1' />
<img src=images/ima2 title='ima2' />
<img src=images/ima3 title='ima3' />
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do what you want.

1 . On another sheet, create a formula that will take the information from the first sheet and produce the HTML you want.

```
="<img src=" & CHAR(34) & INDIRECT("Sheet1!B" &ROW()) & CHAR(34) & " title=" & CHAR(34) & INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & ROW()) & " />"
```

Assuming your data is on Sheet1, every row on your second sheet (with that formula in) will contain the html of the same row on Sheet1. (You'd need to adjust the sheet name and columns if there not the same)

Doing this you can then copy and paste everything from the 2nd sheet.

2 . Using a macro to generate the file.

```
    Public Sub GenerateHTML()
    Dim Handle As Integer
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim Row As Integer

    Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Row = 2

    Handle = FreeFile()

    Open "output.html" For Output As Handle

    Print #Handle, "<html>" & vbNewLine & "<head>" & vbNewLine & "<title>My Gallery...</title>" & vbNewLine & "</head>" & vbNewLine & "<body>"

    Do
        If Sheet.Cells(Row, 1) = "" Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            Print #Handle, "<img src=" & Chr(34) & Sheet.Cells(Row, 2) & Chr(34) & " title=" & Chr(34) & "ima" & Sheet.Cells(Row, 1) & Chr(34) & "/>"
            Row = Row + 1
        End If
    Loop

    Print #Handle, "</body>" & vbNewLine & "</html>"

    Close #Handle

    End Sub
```

This example will create a html file in the same directory as the spreadsheet containing all the links. You'd need to adjust it to suit your needs as its probably not quite right.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a formula in the next column.  Assuming that images/ima1 is in B2 this would be something you could put into C2 to get you what you're after and then paste the formula down.

```
 ="<img src="&B2&" title='"&RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-4)&"' />"
```